# f2py and the WRITE statement

Tags: fortran, f2py

I've tried searching for this answer as it doesn't seem too complicated, but I've had no success.  I'm trying to work with some old FORTRAN code and bring it into Python so I can use it.  In the process I've come across some issues with file I/O, and I'm trying to understand how this would be handled by f2py.  I'm working on Ubuntu 11.10 with gfortran.  For example, I was trying to use the following subroutine:

```
C     FILE INOUT.F

      SUBROUTINE INOUT
     i     (NAME, STUFF)

Cf2py Intent(in,out) NAME, STUFF

      CHARACTER*6 NAME, STUFF

      OPEN(unit=1,file=NAME)
      WRITE(1,100) STUFF
 100  FORMAT(A8) 

      RETURN
      END
```

I then compile using gfortran and f2py:

```
f2py -c -m inout inout.f
```

Which creates the inout.so shared library.  Then in Python, I try a simple test:

```
python
>>> import inout
>>> inout.inout('test','hello')
('test', 'hello ')
```

Then exit out of Python and open the newly created "test" file, and it's empty.  I can print to the screen no problem, but printing to a file doesn't seem to work.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  The f2py documentation doesn't mention WRITE statements.

Comment: what are the version of numpy and gcc of yours? I have numpy (v1.5.1) and gcc (4.1.2) but succeed in outputing the content to `test` file.

Comment: that's weird, coz the same code works for me. I suggest you try to switch to anther fortran compiler for a test. Not sure whether python version would matter, but I am using python2.7, just FYI.

Comment: I got this to work on my home PC with gcc 4.4, and I'm trying to "downgrade" gcc now.  I wonder if this will be a problem?

Comment: gcc is non-trival for most of the libraries and dependencies in your system, I will suggest you first give intel compiler a shot in the computer where it fails.

Answer (score 2):

You can see [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python.scientific.user/2003-10/msg00034.html),

> Python I/O will not catch I/O from Fortran.

Comment: @AshRj ..given the fact that the post's author is presumably the creator of f2py I would consider it a reputable source -- however, in principle you're right.

Comment: @TheodrosZelleke I didnt know that. In that case, yeah, no problem in the answer.

Comment: is that meaning that python usually will not catch `write(*,*)`commands from fortran?

Comment: @Hubschr, the `write` fortran commands will be executed but, probably, not in the way that you want.

Comment: ok... lets say I want to see the output from the `write` command from fortran, in my console, executing the python code... what can happen instead?

Comment: @Hubschr AFAIR the string of Fortran's `write` command will be printed in your console but maybe not in the position that you want.